# combine in 1 cell as value ( text and Date Time in formta yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheets I have 2 cells with temporary status in row.

When I choose in drop down list some text then:

0(status) | 1 | 2 | 3 |

1. add current Date-Time on 1st cell
2. add status from drop down list to 2nd cell

Then I would like to combine (1,2) and paste as value to 3rd cell.

This formula returns my expected result:

```
=IF(AR1="";"";TEXT(AR1;"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"))&"->"&AS1
```

But next I would like to copy those combine status in dynamic range.
If on cell is only Value then I didn't have any problem with it.

But if I try to copy date or formula and paste not like a formula but like a value then Scripts not showing any errors but not working at all.
When I recorder the macro it it's working but when I add small piece of code to change Event - to my code it doesn't.

Probably it's so simple but I try all things to solve it and I don't get why is't working.

I'm new to JavaScript. Please give me some advice why to write the code to paste formula.

```
function onChange(e) {


  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
 var actionCol = 17;
 var mailactionCol = 15;
 var nr_id = 12
   var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(row, actionCol).getValue();
   var mailSourceRange = sheet.getRange(row, mailactionCol).getValue();
   var nr_idRange = sheet.getRange(row, nr_id).getValue();

    //check name of sheets
    var sheetName = sheet.getName()
    if(sheetName != "My_name_sheet"){
       return                            //exit function
    }  

 /
   var currentCOL = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();

  switch(currentCOL) 
 {

/// case is column 15
   case 15:
   //currentCOL = 15
  //id_uniq
       if(mailSourceRange == "" && nr_idRange >0) {return}
       if(mailSourceRange !== "" && nr_idRange =="")
      {
      var msr = sheet.getRange(1, 52);
      var mtr = sheet.getRange(row,12);
      msr.copyTo(mtr, {contentsOnly:true});
      }
     break;

  //case 17 - case is column 17


  case 17:

       var sourceRange1_17 = sheet.getRange(row, 17);
       var sourceRange1_19 = sheet.getRange(row, 19).getValue();
       var sourceRange1_20 = sheet.getRange(row, 20).getValue();

       var targetRange1_18 = sheet.getRange(row, 18);
       var targetRange1_19 = sheet.getRange(row, 19);
       var targetRange1_17 = sheet.getRange(row, 17);
       var targetRange1_20 = sheet.getRange(row, 20);
       var targetRange1_21 = sheet.getRange(row, 21);


     if(sourceRange != "wordInMyCell") {return} {
     if(sourceRange1_20 == "wordInMyCell") {return} 
     // if(sheet.getRange(row, 20).getValue() == "wordInMyCell") {return}

         sourceRange1_17.copyTo(targetRange1_20, {contentsOnly:true});
         targetRange1_19.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss'); 


/// PROBLEMS 
//// 1 not working those method to paste date-time

          targetRange1_19,copyTo(sheet.targetRange1_21, {contentsOnly: true});

  OR 
          sheet.getRange(row, 19).copyTo(sheet.getRange(row, 21), 
           SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);


/// 2 try to add formula to paste on cell not as current row but form recorder 
///    In recorder its works but when i add here to my code it doesn't.


          //       sheet.getRange(row, 18).setFormulaR1C1('=CONCATENATE(U2&" 
                    ";X2&" ";AA2&" ";AD2&" ";AG2&" ";AJ2)');

          var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          var sheet2 = ss2.getSheets()[0];
            var cell2 = sheet2.getRange("U2");
            cell2.setFormula('=IF(V2="";"";W2&TEXT(V2;"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"))');     
  }}}
```

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet (without private or confidential data), but showing what a successful outcome looks like.

Comment: Thank You Tedinoz for your attention. I create a simple file to show my problem. A little bit modicate a statement and now I could paste formula. But I'd like after calculation >. select range (19 columns) and paste all like a value. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aEHCoFV-uzaALbB0Zy4u4fkMrp6aAIFM7jCVXoOgdQU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: May I clarify; please correct me. You have a sheet called "MAIN". Column Q ("Status") is the current Status and is populated by a dropdown. Column R (All Status History) is a concatenated record of status values and dates including the current value assigned to Column Q. There are 6 sets of individual history status (Col: S,T,U; V,W,X; Y,Z,AA; AB,AC,AD; AE,AF,AG & AH,AI,AJ) but these are redundant if the code works effectively. Goal: when Status is changed in Column Q, the current date and status should be added to the history in Column R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chose to use an onChange() trigger, but I would like to suggest:

- use an onEdit(e) trigger
- simply the Status History by capturing ALL history in a single cell (Column R). This has the knock-on effect of also simplifying the code; in particular it reduces the number of `getValue` statements

You'll note:

- concatenation of the Status value and date are achieved by simply joining them with "+". Actually, I added a semi-colon to better distinguish between the status and date.
- I added a line break to each line so that the Status History is easier to read. A disadvantage of this is that the row height increases. You could just as easily delete the line break and/or, say, increase the width of the Status History column.
- If you wish, you may keep the archival columns of Status History, but only one column per set is required.

As usual, there might be several ways that this outcome might be achieved. Consider this answer as one way of doing this.

---

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // 5731586703

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "MAIN";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  // get a list of the event objects
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));


  // get the event source data
  var editedCell = e.range;
  var editRow = editedCell.getRow();
  var editCol = editedCell.getColumn();
  var eValue = e.value;
  var editedSheet = editedCell.getSheet().getName();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the cell = "+editedCell.getA1Notation()+", the column = "+editCol+", the row is "+editRow+", the value is "+eValue+", the edited sheet is "+editedSheet);


  // create some variables for column and row range  
  var statusColumn = 17; // Column Q
  var minstatusRow = 2; // row 2


  // test for a change in column Q, row 2 and higher on Sheet MAIN
  if (editedSheet === sheetname && statusColumn === editCol && editRow>=minstatusRow && eValue.length !=0 ){


    // set the range and value for Column R - ALL_status_history
    var historyrange = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).offset(0,1);
    var historyvalue = historyrange.getValue();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: The history range = "+historyrange.getA1Notation()+", value = "+historyvalue+", length = "+historyvalue.length);

    // get the modified value of the STATUS cell from the event object
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: The Status  value = "+e.value);

    // get the date of the change
    var changeDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),  "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm") ;
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: The change date is "+changeDate);

    // build the value of the modified status and the change date
    var statusHistory = e.value+" "+changeDate;
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the statusHistory is "+statusHistory);

    // if historyvalue is blank
    if (historyvalue.length !=0){
      // there's already some history so insert a blank line
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: there's existing history - insert a line");
      var newhistory = historyvalue+"\n"+statusHistory;
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the new status history = "+newhistory)
    }
    else
    {
      // this is the first entry
      Logger.log("DEBUG: there's no existing history just insert data");
      var newhistory = statusHistory;
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the new status history = "+newhistory)
    }

    // Update the status history
    historyrange.setValue(newhistory);

  }
  else
  {
  // the edited cell wasn't in row2 or higher in Column Q
  // do nothing

  }

}
```

---

Screenshot
[image: Screenhot]

---

**UPDATE- to ensure single use of Status Code**

All status codes can be selected from the dropdown in Column Q, and it is possible to select a status code more than once. However, the Status History should only record a status code once. Therefore, the script should detect whether the selected status code has already been used and, if so, should not update the Status History.

This is achieved  by adding only a few lines of code.

- `var statusExist = historyvalue.indexOf(eValue);`
  This uses the javascript "String" `indexOf()` method which "returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value... it returns -1 if the value is not found." [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- `if (statusExist !=-1){`
  If the method returns -1, then the Status Code hasn't been used before; any other value indicates that the Status Code was found in the "ALL_status_history" field.

---

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // 5731586704

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "MAIN";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  // get a list of the event objects
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));


  // get the event source data
  var editedCell = e.range;
  var editRow = editedCell.getRow();
  var editCol = editedCell.getColumn();
  var eValue = e.value;
  var editedSheet = editedCell.getSheet().getName();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the cell = "+editedCell.getA1Notation()+", the column = "+editCol+", the row is "+editRow+", the value is "+eValue+", the edited sheet is "+editedSheet);


  // create some variables for column and row range  
  var statusColumn = 17; // Column Q
  var minstatusRow = 2; // row 2


  // test for a change in column Q, row 2 and higher on Sheet MAIN
  if (editedSheet === sheetname && statusColumn === editCol && editRow>=minstatusRow && eValue.length !=0 ){


    // set the range and value for Column R - ALL_status_history
    var historyrange = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).offset(0,1);
    var historyvalue = historyrange.getValue();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: The history range = "+historyrange.getA1Notation()+", value = "+historyvalue+", length = "+historyvalue.length);

    // test for an existing Status code in the historyvalue
    var statusExist = historyvalue.indexOf(eValue);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: The status code: " + eValue + " returned " + statusExist); // if -1 = does not exist, any other value = does not exist

    if (statusExist !=-1){
      // do nothing, the statusCode already exists
      Logger.log("DEBUG: do nothing, the Status Code:"+eValue+" has already been used");
    }
    else
    {
      Logger.log("DEBUG: the Status Code:"+eValue+" hasn't been registered yet, so proceed");
      // the status code hasn't been registered yet, so proceed

      // get the modified value of the STATUS cell from the event object
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: The Status  value = "+e.value);

      // get the date of the change
      var changeDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),  "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm") ;
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: The change date is "+changeDate);

      // build the value of the modified status and the change date
      var statusHistory = e.value+" "+changeDate;
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the statusHistory is "+statusHistory);

      // if historyvalue is blank
      if (historyvalue.length !=0){
        // there's already some history so insert a blank line
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: there's existing history - insert a line");
        var newhistory = historyvalue+"\n"+statusHistory;
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: the new status history = "+newhistory)
      }
      else
      {
        // this is the first entry
        Logger.log("DEBUG: there's no existing history just insert data");
        var newhistory = statusHistory;
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: the new status history = "+newhistory)
      }

      // Update the status history
      historyrange.setValue(newhistory);

   }

  }
  else
  {
  // the edited cell wasn't in row2 or higher in Column Q
  // do nothing

  }

}
```

---

**EDIT 13 August 2019**
To allow edit on multiple authorised sheets - achieved by use of SWITCH with minimal changes to code.

- Previous lines 5 and 6 - (`var sheetname` & `getSheetByName`) removed.
- SWITCH inserted  at lines 27 to 43. - assign `var sheetname` where "CASE" name is valid; easy to add/delete/edit valid names.
- IF inserted at line 46; conditionally executes `getSheetByName`
- Line 55 comment - slight edit
- no further changes to code or logic

---

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // 5731586706
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get a list of the event objects
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));  

  // get the event source data
  var editedCell = e.range;
  var editRow = editedCell.getRow();
  var editCol = editedCell.getColumn();
  var eValue = e.value;
  var editedSheet = editedCell.getSheet().getName();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the cell = "+editedCell.getA1Notation()+", the column = "+editCol+", the row is "+editRow+", the value is "+eValue+", the edited sheet is "+editedSheet);

  // create some variables for column and row range  
  var statusColumn = 17; // Column Q
  var minstatusRow = 2; // row 2

  switch (editedSheet) {
    case "MAIN":
      var sheetname = "MAIN";
      break;
    case "AAA":
      var sheetname = "AAA";
      break;
    case "BBB":
      var sheetname = "BBB";
      break;
    case "CCC":
     var sheetname = "CCC";
      break;
    default:
      var sheetname = "";
      break;
  }

  if (sheetname.length !=0){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the name of the edited sheet = "+sheetname);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  }
  else{
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the name of the edited sheet was not on the list");
  }

  // test for a change in column Q, row 2 and higher on a valid sheet
  if (editedSheet === sheetname && statusColumn === editCol && editRow>=minstatusRow && eValue.length !=0 ){

    // set the range and value for Column R - ALL_status_history
    var historyrange = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).offset(0,1);
    var historyvalue = historyrange.getValue();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: The history range = "+historyrange.getA1Notation()+", value = "+historyvalue+", length = "+historyvalue.length);

    // test for an existing Status code in the historyvalue
    var statusExist = historyvalue.indexOf(eValue);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: The status code: " + eValue + " returned " + statusExist); // if -1 = does not exist, any other value = does not exist

    if (statusExist !=-1){
      // do nothing, the statusCode already exists
      Logger.log("DEBUG: do nothing, the Status Code:"+eValue+" has already been used");
    }
    else
    {
      Logger.log("DEBUG: the Status Code:"+eValue+" hasn't been registered yet, so proceed");
      // the status code hasn't been registered yet, so proceed

      // get the modified value of the STATUS cell from the event object
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: The Status  value = "+e.value);

      // get the date of the change
      var changeDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),  "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm") ;
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: The change date is "+changeDate);

      // build the value of the modified status and the change date
      var statusHistory = e.value+" "+changeDate;
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the statusHistory is "+statusHistory);

      // if historyvalue is blank
      if (historyvalue.length !=0){
        // there's already some history so insert a blank line
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: there's existing history - insert a line");
        var newhistory = historyvalue+"\n"+statusHistory;
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: the new status history = "+newhistory)
      }
      else
      {
        // this is the first entry
        Logger.log("DEBUG: there's no existing history just insert data");
        var newhistory = statusHistory;
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: the new status history = "+newhistory)
      }
      // Update the status history
      historyrange.setValue(newhistory);
   }   
  }
  else
  {
  // the edited cell wasn't in row2 or higher in Column Q
  // do nothing
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Tedinoz. Thank You for solution but I have a little problem with it.   in ALL_SATUS_HISTORY in my sheet code paste values double time. "AAA 08/05/2019 08:31
AAA 08/05/2019 08:31"
"BBB 08/05/2019 08:31
BBB 08/05/2019 08:31"

Comment: I delete the tigger and it's works good:)    Thank You Tedinoz.   ps I have a little favor to ask. My code is working with non overwriting. And for me it's importent to modificate your solutions to not possible to add the same status again on row. Thank You in advanced.

Comment: @Gregory_Ame May I clarify; please correct me if I am wrong? All status codes can be selected from a dropdown cell in Column Q, which makes it possible to select a status code more than once. For example: first=AAA, second=BBB, third=AAA (for the second time), etc. However, the Status History should only record a status code once. Therefore, the script should detect whether the selected status code has already been used (details are in "ALL_STATUS_HISTORY") and, if so, should not update the Status History.

Comment: I'm back to Your code Tedinoz and I'd like to ask about something.

Comment: yes Tedinoz. I'm still working on Your brilliant code.:) Thank You for response.  I just try to specify what I want to ask.  OK.  I just try to refer this procedure for not only the MAIN sheet but I'd like to use  also in MAIN, AAA,BBB,CCC but not in DDD sheet.name.  When I try to write something like this it's not working in both but works only for first name CCC .. >>  var sheetname = "CCC" || "DDD";

Comment: @Gregory_Ame Refer edited code. Use of "SWITCH" to identify valid sheets; easy to add/delete/edit sheet names.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I need.