# Send an email when a specific cell is changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to build a project tracker that would

- send an email to a list of emails
- the title of the email is the text from cell A1
- body of email is the text from cell D1
- the trigger is when the value of the cell E1 changes to either "Complete" or "Attention"

So far I've created a script to send emails to the list of people created in a specific sheet. But I'm struggling with the function OnEdit and how to link the cells in single row when sending the email. The spreadsheet will have a number of rows referring to different projects.

```
function sendEmails(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){
    var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    var currentClassTitle = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail,currentClassTitle,"Project complete");
    }
  }
```

Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to use an `onEdit` trigger to check if a cell in column E is changed to "Complete" or "Attention" to send an email with the data from the corresponding row?

Comment: Welcome. This question has been asked and answered many, many times, and there's a reasonable expectation that you will do some initial research.. May I respectfully suggest that you Google "google sheets script email cell change site:.stackoverflow.com" to examine some precedents. After doing this, if you still have a question then raise it as a new question.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315867 for an example how to use onEdit(e) using Event Objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // The sheet.
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues(); // The data in all the cells
  var row = e.range.getA1Notation().substring(1);
  var email = ss.getRange("A"+row).getValue();
  var body = ss.getRange("D"+row).getValue();

  if (e.range.getA1Notation().substring(0,1) == "E"){
    if (data[row-1][4] == "Complete" || data[row-1][4] == "Attention"){
      MailApp.sendEmail(email,currentClassTitle,body);
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I fixed my code, it used to send unnecessary emails and not check properly which cell had been modified. The new code will check if the edited cell was in E column and whether the change was to set it "Complete" or "Attention". If the change was as required it will send a single email to the email on that row, with the content in the body row.

Comment: @Tedinoz you're right, thanks for checking, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Two Event Objects are 1) the edited range and 2) the edited value; run `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` to see all the values. Would it not be better to use these (say, `if (e.range.columnStart == 5){` and `if (e.range.value == "Complete" || e.range.value == "Attention"){`) wherever possible. On a tangent, it's not necessary to `getValues` prior to evaluating the "IF" statements; and even then one needs only `getValues()` from the row that was changed. For example `var data = ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();`